# Separator in android Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-layout

What's the best way to insert a - (dash/minus character) after every 9 characters in a android Edittext, starting from the left?

Examples:

=100001111111111111111111111 -> 100001111-111111111-111111111
My attempt, to show that I have tried doing it myself (a comment below asks: "is this homework?":

```
final int length = string.length();

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(newStringCapacity);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.{9})(?!$)", "$1-");
```

Comment: i dont want to replace it i have e.g 3 phone numbers i want to make array to these three numbers

Comment: @ZohaibNauman This is not replacing anything. It just adds a `-` character after every 9 characters, `$1` means the first regex group, which means that the portion of the string that matches the regex is put back in the resulting string followed by a dash.

Comment: Thanks @titus Done it :)

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you have a definitive number of characters in your `EditText`, I suggest you use [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText). Sample usage from it's docs:

> **Usage**
>
> Add `xmlns:mask="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.app.package"` to your layout xml root. You're now ready to use `MaskedEditText`! Just add to your layout xml:

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    mask:mask="###.###.###-##"
/>
```

`mask` element refers to the format you want. For your case, you could use  `#########-#########-#########`.